# Replace content of all files with some extension

Tags: batch-file, special-characters, replace

I have to replace some content in all files with some specific extension.

For eg: In folder toChange i may have multiple sub folder, now I want to change text `isabcd` to `isxyz` in all the files with extension `html`

what will be the batch for such command, I am using windows

Actually there will be multiple items that i need to replace. I have them in key value form and need to replace all of them one by one in all the files in folder

my text will have double quotes which i want to be replaced
my text will be as follows

```
if (loUserAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") > -1
|| (loUserAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") > -1 && loUserAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie 7") != -1))
```

and i want it to be converted to

```
if (loUserAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf(aaa.FIRE_FOX) > -1
|| (loUserAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf(aaa.MSIE) > -1 && loUserAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf(aaa.IE_7) != -1))
```

the conf.txt file will have inputs like

```
 AAA.PY_ERROR_OCCURRED_WHILE_GETTING_PAYMENT_LIST_SCREEN_FOR_ORG_TYPE:::"Error occurred while getting payment list screen for org type: "
AAA.PY_AO_PAYMENT_LIST_SIZE:::"aoPaymentListSize"
AAA.PY_AO_PAYMENT_STATUS:::"aoPaymentStatus"
```

where text on right side of `:::` is the text that needs to be replaced(with double quotes) and this text may contain special characters as well, and the string on left is the text with which i want it to replace with

PS: sorry about asking direct solution. BUt i have no idea about batch files :(

Comment: are you using linux ??

Comment: I would strongly recommend use `WinGrep`, it has a nice GUI for you.

Comment: @rojo i have cygwin installed, but i barely know how to use it :P

Comment: @rojo - mintty = cygwin terminal???

Comment: Please check the question i have updated the question

Comment: @Varun - I moved my comments to an answer.  See below.

Comment: @Varun: May the CONF.TXT file contain exclamation marks `!`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a hybrid JScript/batch utility named REPL.BAT that can help with this problem. I believe it will be significantly faster than any pure batch solution. Another nice feature is this solution could easily be adapted to do regex search and replace instead of string literal search and replace.

Assuming that my REPL.BAT and your conf.txt are in the same folder as your html files, then the following script should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:: Define LF to contain a newline (0x0A) character
set LF=^


:: The 2 blank lines above are critical - DO NOT REMOVE

:: Read the search and replace strings and store them in an "array"
:: Also, create a variable containing a cascading set of piped commands to
:: carry out each search and replace
:: Normally the search is in the s array, and the replacement in the r array.
:: But if the replacement is an empty string, then the search is in the r array
:: and the s array value is undefined.
set "cnt=0"
set "update="
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (conf.txt) do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  set /a cnt+=1
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for %%n in ("!LF!") do set "ln=!ln::::=%%~n!"
  for %%N in (!cnt!) do (
    for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%U in (""!update!"") do (
      for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("!ln!") do (
        if "!"=="" endlocal
        if not defined r%%N (
          set "r%%N=%%L"
        ) else (
          set "s%%N=%%L"
        )
      )
      if "!"=="" endlocal
      if defined s%%N (
        set "update=%%~U|repl s%%N r%%N vl"
      ) else if defined r%%N (
        set "update=%%~U|repl r%%N "" vl"
      )
    )
  )
)

:: Process each file
for %%F in (*.html) do (
  echo processing %%F
  type "%%F" %update% >"%%F.new"
  move /y "%%F.new" "%%F" >nul
)
echo Done!
```

The script builds an "array" of search and replace strings: `s1,s2,...sn`, and `r1,r2,...rn`

It also builds an `update` command that looks something like

```
|repl s1 r1 vl|repl s2 r2 vl...|repl sn rn vl
```

each file is passed through the set of piped REPL commands that perform the search and replace, one per REPL command.

The script above has the following limitations:

- The final `update` command that I build must be less than 8191 chars long, so there is a limit to the number of search and replace operations that can be performed in one pass. The theoretical limit is around 480 substitutions, though I don't know how Windows will behave with that many pipes in one command.
- None of the search or replacement strings can contain `:::`. This is inherent to the design of your conf.txt file

Here is the REPL.BAT file that is required by the script above. Full documentation is embedded within the script. The script above uses the `V` option to read the search and replace strings from variables, and the `L` option to force a literal search instead of a regex search.

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment

::************ Documentation ***********
:::
:::REPL  Search  Replace  [Options  [SourceVar]]
:::REPL  /?
:::
:::  Performs a global search and replace operation on each line of input from
:::  stdin and prints the result to stdout.
:::
:::  Each parameter may be optionally enclosed by double quotes. The double
:::  quotes are not considered part of the argument. The quotes are required
:::  if the parameter contains a batch token delimiter like space, tab, comma,
:::  semicolon. The quotes should also be used if the argument contains a
:::  batch special character like &, |, etc. so that the special character
:::  does not need to be escaped with ^.
:::
:::  If called with a single argument of /? then prints help documentation
:::  to stdout.
:::
:::  Search  - By default this is a case sensitive JScript (ECMA) regular
:::            expression expressed as a string.
:::
:::            JScript regex syntax documentation is available at
:::            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.80).aspx
:::
:::  Replace - By default this is the string to be used as a replacement for
:::            each found search expression. Full support is provided for
:::            substituion patterns available to the JScript replace method.
:::            A $ literal can be escaped as $$. An empty replacement string
:::            must be represented as "".
:::
:::            Replace substitution pattern syntax is documented at
:::            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/efy6s3e6(v=vs.80).aspx
:::
:::  Options - An optional string of characters used to alter the behavior
:::            of REPL. The option characters are case insensitive, and may
:::            appear in any order.
:::
:::            I - Makes the search case-insensitive.
:::
:::            L - The Search is treated as a string literal instead of a
:::                regular expression. Also, all $ found in Replace are
:::                treated as $ literals.
:::
:::            B - The Search must match the beginning of a line.
:::                Mostly used with literal searches.
:::
:::            E - The Search must match the end of a line.
:::                Mostly used with literal searches.
:::
:::            V - Search and Replace represent the name of environment
:::                variables that contain the respective values. An undefined
:::                variable is treated as an empty string.
:::
:::            M - Multi-line mode. The entire contents of stdin is read and
:::                processed in one pass instead of line by line. ^ anchors
:::                the beginning of a line and $ anchors the end of a line.
:::
:::            X - Enables extended substitution pattern syntax with support
:::                for the following escape sequences:
:::
:::                \\     -  Backslash
:::                \b     -  Backspace
:::                \f     -  Formfeed
:::                \n     -  Newline
:::                \r     -  Carriage Return
:::                \t     -  Horizontal Tab
:::                \v     -  Vertical Tab
:::                \xnn   -  Ascii (Latin 1) character expressed as 2 hex digits
:::                \unnnn -  Unicode character expressed as 4 hex digits
:::
:::                Escape sequences are supported even when the L option is used.
:::
:::            S - The source is read from an environment variable instead of
:::                from stdin. The name of the source environment variable is
:::                specified in the next argument after the option string.
:::

::************ Batch portion ***********
@echo off
if .%2 equ . (
  if "%~1" equ "/?" (
    findstr "^:::" "%~f0" | cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "^:::" ""
    exit /b 0
  ) else (
    call :err "Insufficient arguments"
    exit /b 1
  )
)
echo(%~3|findstr /i "[^SMILEBVX]" >nul && (
  call :err "Invalid option(s)"
  exit /b 1
)
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
exit /b 0

:err
>&2 echo ERROR: %~1. Use REPL /? to get help.
exit /b

************* JScript portion **********/
var env=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("Process");
var args=WScript.Arguments;
var search=args.Item(0);
var replace=args.Item(1);
var options="g";
if (args.length>2) {
  options+=args.Item(2).toLowerCase();
}
var multi=(options.indexOf("m")>=0);
var srcVar=(options.indexOf("s")>=0);
if (srcVar) {
  options=options.replace(/s/g,"");
}
if (options.indexOf("v")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/v/g,"");
  search=env(search);
  replace=env(replace);
}
if (options.indexOf("l")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/l/g,"");
  search=search.replace(/([.^$*+?()[{\\|])/g,"\\$1");
  replace=replace.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$");
}
if (options.indexOf("b")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/b/g,"");
  search="^"+search
}
if (options.indexOf("e")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/e/g,"");
  search=search+"$"
}
if (options.indexOf("x")>=0) {
  options=options.replace(/x/g,"");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\\\/g,"\\B");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\b/g,"\b");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\f/g,"\f");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\n/g,"\n");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\r/g,"\r");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\t/g,"\t");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\v/g,"\v");
  replace=replace.replace(/\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}/g,
    function($0,$1,$2){
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt("0x"+$0.substring(2)));
    }
  );
  replace=replace.replace(/\\B/g,"\\");
}
var search=new RegExp(search,options);

if (srcVar) {
  WScript.Stdout.Write(env(args.Item(3)).replace(search,replace));
} else {
  while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
    if (multi) {
      WScript.Stdout.Write(WScript.StdIn.ReadAll().replace(search,replace));
    } else {
      WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(WScript.StdIn.ReadLine().replace(search,replace));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @varun - I've rewritten my code to minimize limitations. I haven't tested, but the design will definitely work. If the code does not work, then I have a silly bug that can be fixed. Just let me know.

Comment: @varun - Well I finally tested and debugged the code. It now works perfectly :-) I must have had half a dozen bugs before.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Load the replacement table from conf.txt file
set n=0
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%~P0conf.txt") do (
   set "line=%%a"
   set /A n+=1
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   rem Use the first special character here, after second equal-sign and 15 characters forward
   rem and the second special character after the third equal-sign
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=Ç" %%b in ("!n!Ç!line::::=ü!") do (
      endlocal
      set "replace[%%b]=%%c"
   )
)

rem Process all HTML files in toChange folder
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
cd "C:\toChange"
for /R %%a in (*.html) do (
   rem Process all lines of this file
   (for /F "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do (
      set "line=%%b"
      setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
      rem Make the replacements
      for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do (
         rem Use the second special character here, after second equal-sign
         for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=ü" %%c in ("!replace[%%i]!") do (
            set "line=!line:%%d=%%c!"
         )
      )
      echo !line!
      endlocal
   )) > "%%a.txt"
   rem Remove the REM in next lines to delete original .html file and rename the created one
   REM del "%%a"
   REM ren "%%a.txt" "%%~NXa"
)
```

The Batch program above generate its output in files with the same names as the originals and ".txt" extension added. If the result is correct, remove the REM commands at end of the Batch file to delete the original .hmtl file and rename the created one. I tested the program with this data:

**conf.txt**

```
AAA.PY_ERROR_OCCURRED_WHILE_GETTING_PAYMENT_LIST_SCREEN_FOR_ORG_TYPE:::"Error occurred while getting payment list screen for org type: "
AAA.PY_AO_PAYMENT_LIST_SIZE:::"aoPaymentListSize"
AAA.PY_AO_PAYMENT_STATUS:::"aoPaymentStatus"
aaa.FIRE_FOX:::"firefox"
aaa.MSIE:::"msie"
aaa.IE_7:::"msie 7"
```

**example.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<!-- Example HTML file -->

Normal text. <b>Bold text.</b> <i>Italic text.</i>

if (loUserAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") > -1
|| (loUserAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") > -1 && loUserAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie 7") != -1))
```

Output: **example.html.txt**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<!-- Example HTML file -->
Normal text. <b>Bold text.</b> <i>Italic text.</i>
if (loUserAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf(aaa.FIRE_FOX) > -1
|| (loUserAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf(aaa.MSIE) > -1 && loUserAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf(aaa.IE_7) != -1))
```

The conf.txt file must be in the same folder of the Batch file.

The program remove empty lines from the input file. This may be easily fixed if you want to.

The program may be somewhat slow. This may be improved at some degree, but with extensive modifications.

**EDIT**: I modified previous version of this program in order to:

- Correctly process exclamation marks in conf.txt file.
- Use a special character to separate the replacement values of conf.txt file instead of equal-sign.

Please note that you may use a combination of characters as separators in your own text, like `:::`, but in certain Batch management the separator must be just *one* character. This detail force us to choose a certain character that must not appear inside conf.txt file. My program require *two* different special characters to be used as separators. I choosen Ascii character 128 (Ç) and 129 (ü); if these characters may appear in conf.txt file, then you must select another ones and change they at the indicated points in the program. Sorry, there is no other way to do this in a Batch file.

Comment: +1, Nice Aacini. This should work as long as none of the search strings contain `=` (perhaps a problem), and also as long as blank lines do not need to be preserved, which should not be a problem for html files. Also, each line must be less than 8191 bytes long.

Comment: my search string can have`/` `\` `=` or any other special char it may look like `"\"text=ab/cd\"

Answer (score 0):

Launch `mintty.exe` (your cygwin terminal) and execute the following command.  Modify `/cygdrive/c/Users/etc` as appropriate.

> `find /cygdrive/c/Users/Varun/Documents/etc/toChange -type f -iname '*.html' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -r -e "/aaa\.[A-Z1-9_]+\s*=/!s/\Wfirefox\W/aaa.FIRE_FOX/g" -e "/aaa\.[A-Z1-9_]+\s*=/!s/\Wmsie 7\W/aaa.IE_7/g" -e "/aaa\.[A-Z1-9_]+\s*=/!s/\Wmsie\W/aaa.MSIE/g"`

That means:

- within `/path/to/toChange`,
- find `f`iles (not directories) with a `.html` extension
- pass each match to `sed`, which will modify the contents inline.
- For each line **not** containing `var aaa.FIRE_FOX =` or similar,

  - globally search for `[non alpha-numeric]firefox[non alpha-numeric]`
  - and replace with `aaa.FIRE_FOX`

... and so on.

**test.html** before:

```
var aaa.FIRE_FOX="firefox"
var aaa.MSIE="msie"
var aaa.IE_7="msie 7"
if (loUserAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") > -1
|| (loUserAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") > -1 && loUserAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie 7") != -1))
```

**test.html** after the `find | xargs sed` command:

```
var aaa.FIRE_FOX="firefox"
var aaa.MSIE="msie"
var aaa.IE_7="msie 7"
if (loUserAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf(aaa.FIRE_FOX) > -1
|| (loUserAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf(aaa.MSIE) > -1 && loUserAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf(aaa.IE_7) != -1))
```

If this doesn't work for you, maybe Endoro's suggestion of using something with a GUI such as WinGrep might be better

Comment: thanks for the answer, but `loUserAgent` is not a prerequisite the only requirement is to change `"firefox"` to `aaa.FIRE_FOX`

Comment: and my files may have multiple occurrence of `"firefox"` or other words/strings i need to replace

Comment: Updated again.  If that doesn't do what you want, I strongly encourage you to find another solution.